Difference Between Plasma Potential and Floating Potential in a Plasma
I'm learning about Langmuir probes and I'm confused about the difference between the plasma potential $V_p$ and the floating potential $V_f$.
From my understanding, when a plasma is in contact with a surface, the plasma will acquire a positive potential will respect to that surface due to the initially higher flux of electrons out of the plasma (compared to the ions). The potential it acquires is such that the currents of ions and electrons out of the plasma to the surface are forced to be equal. This potential, with respect to the surface can be approximated as,
$V_p - V_{surface} \approx \frac{kT_e}{e}ln\left(\frac{m_i}{2\pi m_e}\right)^{1/2}$
The above quantity is the plasma potential correct? So if my plasma is sitting inside a grounded metal vacuum chamber, then the bulk of the plasma will be sitting at a potential $V_p$ above ground?
If so, then what exactly is the floating potential? When it comes to Langmuir probe theory, the floating potential is described as being a distinct quantity from the plasma potential. Assuming the probe is being biased with respect to the same grounded chamber, the floating potential is defined as the bias voltage "at which the electron and ion currents to it are equal". Since the plasma biased itself to $V_p$ above the grounded chamber to ensure equal currents to the chamber, does that mean the floating potential of the probe must always be 0V (w.r.t ground)? It seems like in general, this is not the case, hence my confusion.
I have also seen the floating potential described as the "potential an electrically isolated surface acquires with respect to the plasma". By electrically isolated surface, do we mean some conductor that is isolated from any other conductors (like, hypothetically, a metal surface just floating in space in the plasma)?

When you have several different current sources and they eventually reach a balance (i.e., $\sum_{s} \mathbf{j}_{s} = 0$), sometimes conductive surfaces still have a net electric potential.  If this is the case, it is often called a floating potential.  Spacecraft in the sunlight tend to charge positive, thus have a net positive floating potential.

The floating potential is the potential a metallic body acquires in the plasma when it is not connected to any electrode, so that the charged fluxes arriving to it have no where to go but to change its potential with respect to the plasma.
It is typically lower than the plasma potential. As you mentioned, for the electrons and the ion fluxes arriving to the floating metal to be equal, the ambipolar field must be set around the floating metal (i.e. in the sheath). For an electric field to exist one needs to have a potential difference. One one side there is the plasma potential, on the other side (floating metal). So roughly:
(Vp-Vf)/sheath_width = ambipolar_field
Note that I prioritized simplicity over accuracy in this answer

So in the example I gave, of a plasma in a grounded vacuum chamber, would the floating potential be somewhere in between ground and the plasma potential?
I guess one of my points of confusion is, what is the reference point for the plasma potential? Is it the potential of the plasma with respect to the grounded chamber?

The reference of the plasma potential is the grounded chamber. The floating potential of a floating conductor in the plasma is typically negative, which makes sense considering that once the plasma forms electrons rush to the floating metal giving it a negative charge. In a way the electrons that charged the floating metal reduce the electron flux from the plasma to the floating metal and increase the flux of the positive ions until it is equal to that of the electrons. This is another way to understand how the ambipolar field forms

This cleared some things up thank you! There is one thing that confused me. So the plasma will establish a potential Vp with respect to the grounded chamber so the particles fluxes to the chamber are balanced. If a floating probe is stuck into the plasma, won't it just develop a potential -Vp with respect to the plasma so the particle fluxes to itself are balanced. I think I'm confused as to why the floating potential in this scenario doesn't just become ground.

"the particles fluxes to the chamber are balanced" this is not the case, typically the walls of the chamber serve as the counter electrode (if the plasma is driven by biasing the cathode, the walls are the anode), so it does draw current. When we say floating object what we mean by that is that it is not connected to any electrode. If the floating probe has a potential of 0 V that means it is connected to the ground and thus the electrons cannot build the field required to hinder further electrons from flowing into the probe because they will just go to the ground right?
